# Static Cache - Two "Instances"

Tags: java, caching

I have an application where I need two static caches, once short-term and one long-term.

So I have an abstract class that looks something like this.  My thought was that I would create two classes that inherit from this abstract class, thereby attaining my two static classes.

However, it occurs to me that I am creating 3 objects when I might be able to get by with one.  But I am at a loss in how to do so.  Do I want some sort of factory class?

Can someone suggest an appropriate pattern here?

```
public abstract class myCache {
    static Map<String, Object> ObjectCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();

    public void put(String Key, T cmsObject) {
    //
    }

      public xxx static get(String objectKey, Class<T> type) {
    //
    }
}
```

Comment: All you need is one class with two static fields, one for short-term and the other for long-term.

Comment: I didn't see you creating 3 objects from your question. Do you mean 3 *classes* ?  Honestly you time-to-live is not really something that you need to use inheritance to achieve. Follow @Bohemian's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is flawed:

- A cache is a cache - let the caching class take care of caching... **only**
- Unless the number of objects is large (1000's), don't let the "number of objects created" influence your design
- Only the *user* of your cache class needs to know or care what how the cache is being used

Thus:

```
public class MyClass {

    private static MyCache shortTermCache = new MyCache();
    private static MyCache longTermCache = new MyCache();

}
```

You may consider passing a time-to-live parameter into your cache class constructor to let it manage purging after a certain time.

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class myCache {

    static ConcurrentMap<Class<?>,Map<String, Object>> ObjectCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<Class<?>,Map<String, Object>>();

    {
         ObjectCache.putIfAbsent(getClass(),new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Object>());
    }

    public void put(String Key, Object cmsObject) {
         ObjectCache.get(this.getClass()).put(key,cmsObject);
    }

    public Object get(String objectKey) {
         return ObjectCache.get(this.getClass()).get(key);
    }
}
```